# How can I install crown cornice molding and trim on rounded outside corners?

Tags: walls, trim, finishing

We have rounded outside corners throughout our house what is the best approach to installing crown cornice molding?

The baseboards that are currently installed just come to a 90˚ point and the gap is filled in with putty, trim paint, mud, or combination thereof.

Any suggestions for a finely finished look to go with the rounded corners?

Comment: I've never used it -- I prefer the angled look like in Doresoom's answer below -- but have you looked into [flexible crown molding](http://www.google.com/search?q=flexible+crown+molding).

Comment: didnt undestand , what degrees you used for this corner?
bevel and miter

Comment: what is the approximate diameter of the curve?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can add a center section at the corner that runs at a 45° angle to either wall. That cuts down on any gap you might have, but makes the installation and cutting a bit more difficult. My house has a few faux pillars that use this technique:

[image]

(I know, I know, I haven't gotten around to touch ups after we painted the walls...)

And here's a lookup table for cutting crown molding ([source](http://www.extremehowto.com/xh/article.asp?article_id=60354)):

[image]

Comment: Nice answer and great chart. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Keep in mind that the chart is useless if you assume that corners are 90 degrees.  You've got to accurately measure.